# How to zoom in/out d3.time.scale without scaling other shapes bound to timeline

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, scale

http://jsfiddle.net/HF57g/ is an example of a single event(blue rect) placed on the timeline. If i zoom into the timeline, rect's placement on the x axis changes in harmony with the ticks on axis. but at the same time, rect is scaled horizontally.

if i modify the following section of the code

```
svg.selectAll(".item").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0]+", 0)scale(" + d3.event.scale+", 1)");
```

to

```
svg.selectAll(".item").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0]+", 0)scale(1, 1)");
```

as in http://jsfiddle.net/HF57g/1/ to disable horizontal scaling, then the rect's position changes much more than the axis' during zoom in/out.

How can i zoom in/out time.scale without scaling other related shapes?

Comment: could you perhaps accept your answer (by pressing checkmark beside it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up adding an update function to rearrange the rects' places depending on the new positions returned by scale(x).

```
function update_events(){
    return svg.selectAll("rect.item")
        .attr("x", function(d){return scale(d);})    
}
```

Here's the final version: http://jsfiddle.net/HF57g/2/

Comment: you should accept your own answer so that the question is no longer "unanswered"